# Tapestry - Passing Parameters to method from tml

Tags: java, tapestry

Is it possible to pass a parameter to the method which is being defined in controller, and called by tml ?

**tml**

```
${getDynamicFieldValue("Subject")}
```

**java**

```
public String getDynamicFieldValue(String fieldToCompare) 
{
    //Logic
}
```

**Exception**

```
Could not convert 'getDynamicFieldValue("Subject")' into a component parameter binding: Error parsing property expression 'getDynamicFieldValue("Subject")': Unable to parse input at character position 22.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, it is possible. However, you must use single quotes around string literals:

```
${getDynamicFieldValue('Subject')}
```

Check the [documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/property-expressions.html) for more information on property expressions.

Comment: Is it possible to pass more than one parameter to the method ? According to my experience, it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to pass multiple arguments.

${getDynamicFieldValue('Subject', 'Object')}

where you have a method
public String getDynamicFieldValue(String arg1, String arg2) ...